# How to calculate the Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series, signal-processing

How to calculate the Fourier coefficients, of a given input : 
$$u(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\overline u_k e^{ik\omega_0t}$$ of this output:
$$v(t)=u(t)(1-cos^2(\omega_0t))$$ 
So how is the mathematical definition of this, maybe started from the definition of Fourier series. So how can I start this ?

Comment: What's your formula for the fourier coefficient?  Does $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) e^{2\pi int}dt$ look familiar?

Comment: Hmmmm I think I have to found $a_0, a_n \ and \ b_n$ or not?

Comment: Try expanding $1-\cos^2(\omega_0 t)$ into complex exponentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$v(\Omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(t)e^{{i}\Omega{t}}dt-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(t)\cos^{2}(\omega_{0}t)e^{{i}\Omega{t}}dt=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}u(\Omega)-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(t)\frac{e^{2i\omega_{0}t}+e^{-2i\omega_{0}t}}{4}e^{{i}\Omega{t}}dt=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}u(\Omega)-\frac{1}{4}u(\Omega+2\omega_{0})-\frac{1}{4}u(\Omega-2\omega_{0})$$

Comment: Sorry, but $\Omega$ is instant of what?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a summation index. You name it $k$